# Power bi AUTO resize zoom bug

Tags: powerbi

I have a report and all of its tabs has a zoom set to 100% unless one where it's set to 38% if a zoom this tab to 100% and save so power bi forgot my changings and auto resize 100% to 38% in this tab this bug was created when I clicked in "fit to the page" located in the bottom left.

I tried to see all configs in the power bi and clicking "fit to the page" again but getting nothing.